# Executing one subroutine without opening Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to know if there is an easy workaround for my following question. I have an access database that have different modules in vba (and of course each module with different subroutines). How can I do to create an icon or an executable file that by clicking on it it runs one of the subroutines of one of the modules without opening access?

The reason of this is because when I am away people need to run some of these subroutines and these users don't have any experience with Access.

Comment: Why not just create an Access file that will run the procedures on startup and then closes itself?

Comment: I agree with Marek, create a file to run what you need at startup, then close itself. I don't know if it's possible to run just a function from an access file without opening, but I'm willing to bet it's a lot harder to do than open file, run function, close file.

Answer (score 2):

You can start Access with a command line option to run a named Access macro.  (That means an Access macro object.  Some people also call VBA procedures macros, but an Access macro object is different.)

An Access macro has a `RunCode` method which you can use to run a VBA function.  Since the code you want to run is a subroutine, create a new function which calls that subroutine and shuts down Access afterward, and use the function with the macro's `RunCode` method.

After you have the macro working correctly, test it from a Windows Command Prompt session following this pattern:

```
"<path to MSACCESS.EXE>" "<path to db file>" -X <macro name>
```

After working out those details, you can create a desktop shortcut to do the same thing.

However, if your Access operation must be run by you or another user on a regularly scheduled basis (daily, weekdays only, etc.), you could create a Windows Scheduled Task to do it and forget about other users and desktop shortcuts.

Note this suggestion isn't exactly what you requested because it does open Access.  But it could close Access after the operation is finished, so perhaps it will be acceptable.